# JQuery Slide Function Not Working Right

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, mouse, mouseover

Well im making a drop down menu, but having trouble with the drop part. It works if go on top of the button once, but sometimes it goes crazy and if i go on to once in will go under and down many time.
That my code...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var par = $('#subitem');
  $(par).hide();
  $('#barbox').mouseover(function(a) {
      $(par).slideToggle(300);
      a.preventDefault();
  });
  $(par).mouseleave(function(a) {
      $(par).slideToggle(300);
  });
});
</script>
```

You can see the problem on my [site](http://sy-webs.comoj.com/), just go over services tab and fool around with the mouse there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your animation goes crazy is due to the animation queue in Jquery.

What you want to do is stop the queue before doing the slideToggle event like so:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var par = $('#subitem');
  $(par).hide();
  $('#barbox').mouseover(function(a) {
      $(par)
.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
      a.preventDefault();
  });
  $(par).mouseleave(function(a) {
      $(par)
.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
  });
});
</script>
```

check out this link for more info: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

try putting all the events in the same function like this:

```
$('#subitem').mouseenter(function(){
      $('#subitem').slideToggle(300);
      a.preventDefault();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      $('#subitem').slideToggle(300);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your HTML first. You use the same id on each td of your table. The same for the links.
An id is unique, so you should use a class instead.